# Level progression grid/chart

Tags: mathematics, gui, character, progression

What I'd like to do is create a sheet where I can track character XP/level progression.

I created this by hand:

[image: Drawing]

It's sloppy, but in the realm of what I'd like to generate on a computer. Each bar represents XP needed to level up, with each square on the grid representing a set number of XP.

Any ideas how I could go about doing this in a more standardized/repeatable/printable?

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. You want to put this into a document and re-print it? While it's related to game development, it sounds more like a [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) type question. Or a question specific to the application you want to use.

Comment: So you want to have something on computer where it is shown how many XP there are for each level and where you can tick off or otherwise mark how many XP the character already has for the appropriate level. As Byte56 already mentioned it would be good to know what you want there exactly in terms of what you want out of the whole thing:
Something you can use programmatically, or a document (charsheet for example), a pdf, ... . and if oyu want it to be created time and again or only once. That would be useful infos so that ppl can give you appropriate help there.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you wrote, it seems the progression of each number of squares in a block is `(2k - 1) where k > 0` You can extend this to include the amount of XP per block as: `(2k - 1) * c where k > 0, c > 0` The constant value can be tweaked as needed for gameplay purposes.

If you are talking about trying to represent the drawn bars *graphically* then it is simply: `((2k - 1) * c) % PIXEL_WIDTH where k is the level number, c is the number of pixels per square, PIXEL_WIDTH is the max pixels per horizontal bar.`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something less technical (I don't have any coding skills). Any ideas how I can do this with standard software?